# Issue in getting db data using Hibernate query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Please look below db table relationship

comapny to product->many to many

product to item->many to many

Now, I need to get All items used in a company by using hibernate. Below is my efforts.

```
Criteria c = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Company.class);
c.add(Restrictions.eq("companyId", companyId));

Criteria c2 = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Item.class);
c2.add(c);//not correct parameter and trying to correct

List<Item> data = c2.list();
```

Above code is not correct. Please help me by giving right direction!

Comment: Are the associations bidirectional? Why are you using the criteria API instead of using HQL? Why do you use a raw List? Have you read the documentation?

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your quick response! Associations are birirectional. I am exploring how to do using HQL. I am not using raw list and also edited in post now.

Comment: This is something you should figure out by yourself, using the documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins